# Non-functioning microphone or camera on Thinkpad x1 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: microphone, camera

Since I got my Thinkpad X1 with Ubuntu 20.04, my camera won't work on any application and the same applies for my microphone.

Here are the results of `lsusb` if that helps:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:012d Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS 5011 fingerprint sensor
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here are the results of `lspci:`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI KT (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

I am fairly new to ubuntu and the various forms of linux. Help is needed and any is appreciated. Thank you